# ASP.NET set value in Repeater and have it passed into codebehind

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater, hyperlink

I have a list of `asp:HyperLink` created by a `Repeater`. When I click on one of these `HyperLinks` I want it to pass the value set in the `HyperLink` into the code behind so I know which `HyperLink` has been clicked. So...

```
<asp:Repeater id="rpt1" runat="server">
    ...some rows of HyperLinks..
   <li><asp:HyperLink ID="hlValue" CssClass='example8' NavigateUrl="#" 
       OnClick="passavalue(books)" >books</asp:hyperlink></li>
    ...
</asp:repeater>
```

c#

```
static void passavalue(string value)
{
    response.Write(vlaue);
}
```

I know this wont work I'm just trying to explain what I'm trying to do.

Comment: For some reason stack overflow ripped out all the html i wrote so this makes no sense. 

<br />
<br />
<asp:HyperLink ID="hlValue" onclick="passavalue(value of this hyperlink)" CssClass='example8' NavigateUrl="#" runat="server"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Name") %></asp:HyperLink>
<br /><br />




static void passavalue(string value) { response.Write(vlaue); }
<br /><br />

Comment: When the HyperLink is clicked, do you want something to happen without a page refresh, eg. via Ajax?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet in my opinion would be to use a QueryString or Route parameter in the NavigationUrl you set for each hyperlink...  Your repeater could set the custom value for each link using the DataBinder behavior <%# Eval("") %> etc...

Comment: when they click the hyperlink its opening a colorbox where i have another repeater, depending on what they have clicked i want to order the repeater in the colorbox so that the value they have clicked appears first. If i use the navigateurl this would take me off the page to apply the querystrin, which i dont want to do. i need it to run a method when clicked.

Comment: Ah, in that case, you are going to have to either go with the approach from below by Peter, or you will need to do your manipulation in javascript using a similar function call..like your "passavalue()"..

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use an **asp:linkbutton** instead of the asp:hyperlink in your ItemTemplate.

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="DoSomethingLink" CommandName="DoSomething" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Name") %>'><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Name") %></asp:LinkButton>
```

You would then handle the Repeater's ItemCommand event.

```
protected void YourRepeater_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e) 
{ 
    if (e.CommandName == "DoSomething") 
    { 
        var arg = e.CommandArgument; 
        // do something ...
    } 
}
```

Comment: I would add that LinkButton is a regular hyperlink that uses JavaScript to POST to the server (to simulate a real button), and thus has Accessibility and SEO issues. I would avoid it's use on a public facing site, but an internal/intranet site is fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by binding to the `CommandArgument` some value (probably an ID I would guess).  Here is an example of a `LinkButton` that you could add to your `Repeater` `ItemTemplate`:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <div>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="lbTest" runat="server"
            CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>' Text='<%# Eval("Text") %>' 
            OnClick="lbTest_Click" />
    </div>
</ItemTemplate>
```

You can then grab the value server side by implementing the `OnClick` for the `LinkButton`.  You can you the same even for all buttons in the repeater if you want and not have to bother with the `RowCommand` event.

```
protected void lbTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton lb = (LinkButton)(sender);
    string valueYouWanted = lb.CommandArgument;
    // do something with it
}
```

**Edit:** Based on reading your code added, if you want to stick to using a `asp:HyperLink` and not a link button, the `OnClick` will fire javascript, not server side so you would need to use the `<%# Eval("ID") %>` (or whatever field you want get use) to add the unique identifier to your javascript inline.  Example:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="hlValue" CssClass='example8' NavigateUrl="#"  
    OnClick='passavalue(<%# Eval("YourBookID") %>)' >books</asp:hyperlink>
```

Comment: @phil crowe did any of these answers work for you?  If not, edit your question and we can try and come up with some better answers.